# JAVA: reference defined within a loop

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I'm just curious.
suppose I define a reference inside a while/for loop.

does the JVM define this reference every iteration, or it's optimized to define it only once?

Comment: What do you mean, "define"?  It really depends what you mean.  The variable will be reinitialized every time, but the memory space will probably get reused.

Comment: What do you mean by "define a reference"?  Strictly speaking, the reference is the value of the variable, which is a far cry from allocating an object.  Those two interpretations have very different answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It defines every time and scoped to only that loop iteration.

As soon as loop iteration done, it is eligible for GC.

As Louis Wasserman commented, The variable will be reinitialized every time, but the memory space will probably get reused.

Comment: It will not be eligible for GC. The stack slot will continue to exist until reused by a subsequent variable declared after the loop, if any, otherwise until the method exits. There is no JVM instruction corresponding to the closing brace of the loop, so no way for the JVM to know that the slot is no longer in use.

Comment: @Ejp: I am happy to update my answer, but could you provide any references? i think heap is the location which will be gced, not stack frame.

Comment: @EJP - If the slot is overwritten by a new value, the old object becomes eligible for collection.

Comment: @HotLicks Of course, that's why I mentioned it. I should have clarified that only the last iteration of the loop leaves a dangling slot, until the slot gets reused or released.

Comment: The heap is GC'd. The stack contains references to the heap. The stack slot occupied by the OP's loop variable is allocated at the beginning of the method and released at the end of the method. Until then, it is capable of holding a reference, and thus preventing GC of the referenced object. If you want to debate this *you* need to show a JVM instruction corresponding to the closing brace of a loop, or another plausible mechanism whereby the reference in the loop variable can get released, instead of just blindly asserting it without proof.

Comment: @EJP -- The location can (and likely will) be "repurposed" in any substantial method, after it's passed out of scope.  And a JIT will likely reuse the slot even within a given scope, if possible.

Comment: @HotLicks That's why I mentioned both those possibilities. You seem to be trying to invent disagreements where none exist.

Answer (score 4):

The reference is defined on each iteration. Once the code has been optimised to native code, it could be moved outside the loop so it doesn't have to have a performance impact.  If you set this reference to a `new` object each time, it may create a new object on each iteration unless that object creation has been optimised away also.

Answer (score 2):

Its defined every time. There is no optimization for that (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

**-** The **defines the reference everytime** the loop iterates, but the scope of the reference is attached only to that iteration.

**-** Consider that you have **declared a reference outside the loop**, but **assign object** to it **inside** the loop, then the reference remains the same , but it reference new object of that type in every iteration.